# Android using JSON url to load images in List

Tags: android, json, image, tumblr

I currently have this code with the purl.getString("url") containing url links to jpg images online. I would like to display these images in a list or grid but cannot understand how. The current code simply lists all of the URLs in listview but just want those URL's to be their respective images.

Here is my code

```
public class BreadActivity extends ListActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, this.fetchJsonStuff()));
       }

public ArrayList<String> fetchJsonStuff()
{
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        URL example = new URL(
                "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/example.tumblr.com");
        URLConnection tc = example.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                tc.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(line);
            JSONObject object = ob.getJSONObject("response");
            JSONArray ja = object.getJSONArray("posts");

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                JSONArray nja = (JSONArray) jo.getJSONArray("photos");

            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < nja.length(); i1++) {
                JSONObject njo = (JSONObject) nja.get(i1);
                JSONObject purl = (JSONObject) njo.getJSONObject("original_size");
                listItems.add(purl.getString("url"));

            }

            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listItems;
}

  }
```

Comment: Can you provide resultant string ???